# How to force handleFault() to be called

Tags: java, cxf

I had implemented a handler with Apache CXF web service. My intention is to trace the exceptions & log more information.
Snippet from handler code is something as follows

```
public class SoapFaultHandler  implements SOAPHandler<SOAPMessageContext> {

    @Override
    public boolean handleMessage(SOAPMessageContext context) {
       //what should be thrown from here or web service so that handleFault() is called
       

    }
    @Override
    public boolean handleFault(SOAPMessageContext context) {
    }
    //......................
}
```

I had tried throwing javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException() from handleMessage(), but handleFault was not called.  Can someone please give some hint?

**Edit:**
The exceptions throw from handleMessage()  was not reaching the handleFault() defined in the same handler. However of late I find that the handleFault() gets called when I throw SoapFault exceptions from the web service.
Below is a snippet of the code.

```
 catch(CustomException e)
 { 
   String codeStr =//custom string here
   QName faultCode = new  QName("http://cxf.apache.org/soapfault",codeStr);
   String faultString = e.toString();
   SoapFault soapFault = new SoapFault(faultString,faultCode);
   throw soapFault;
}
```

In the Java client, this was coming as SOAPFaultException and I had to call  <exception_obj>.getCause() to get the CXF SoapFault object.

Comment: Where/how is this handler registered with CXF? Depending on the context in which you're using CXF (such as Spring or a Java EE container) it might need a specific annotation, or added to some sort of context object.

Comment: @JeroenSteenbeeke Its registered through the cxf-beans.xml file under WEB-INF folder. Something as <jaxws-handlers><bean class="packagename.SoapFaultHandler"/></jaxws-handlers>. My web service is deployed on tomcat

Answer (score 0):

You can register IN/OUT Fault interceptors in the Endpoint registration.

```java
    @Bean
    public Endpoint awesomeEndpoint() {
        EndpointImpl endpoint = new EndpointImpl(springBus(), awesomeServiceImpl());

        endpoint.getInFaultInterceptors().add(new AwesomeFaultInInterceptor());
        endpoint.getOutFaultInterceptors().add(new AwesomeFaultOutInterceptor());
            
        endpoint.publish("/awesomeService");
        
        return endpoint;
    }
```